# How to reference environment variable inside startswith github actions statement

Tags: github-actions

I have the following github actions code:

```
    env: 
      HEAD_REF: ${{ github.head_ref }} 
    if: ${{ ! startsWith($HEAD_REF, 'random/name') }}
    steps: ...
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/name.yml (Line: 16, Col: 9): Unexpected symbol: '$HEAD_REF'. Located at position 14 within expression: ! startsWith($HEAD_REF, 'random/name')
```

In the github docs it says "An expression can be any combination of literal values, references to a context, or functions.". Can you not reference environment variables inside some github expressions or is something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: `if (env.HEAD_REF)`

Comment: Or directly `if: ${{ ! startsWith(github.head_ref, 'rand/name') }}`, instead of via `env`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
if: ${{ ! startsWith( github.head_ref, 'random/name') }}
```

Github doesn't let you reference environment variables in these expressions, but it lets you reference the default env variables they provide

Comment: This might be a minor detail, but to make sure you don't confuse yourself with terminology: `github` and similar constructs (like `inputs`, `jobs`, `matrix`, `vars` etc.) are called [*contexts*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). `env` is also a context, so the environment is available like that, too.

Comment: Also, the reason why `env.HEAD_REF` didn't work: the `if` key on the job-level (which is what you have) supports only these contexts: `github`, `needs`, `vars`, `inputs` (see [this list](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability)).